# Как выровнять элементы на Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Элементы стоят в одну строку. Нужно выровнять меню так, что бы оно всегда оставалось ровно по-середине страницы. 
Вот 
  [ПРИМЕР](https://jsfiddle.net/157dr96p/1/)

```css
.box_navbar_collapse {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
}
.navbar-nav >li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.box_tell>p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.box_tell {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_navbar_collapse">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="img/index/logo.png" alt="">
  </a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">text</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">text</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button class="btn">кнопка</button>
  <div class="box_tell">
    <p>(097) 948-61-83</p>
    <p>(095) 836-90-32</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
  <span>|</span>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
  <span>center</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;}`

Answer (score 1):

Сделал пример и обновил твой JSFidlle:

***HTML:***

```
<div class="box_navbar_collapse">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/25/MOT_Approved_Test_station_symbol.png" alt="MY-LOGO">
    </a>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li> <a href="#">Меню 1</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#">Меню 2</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#">Меню 3</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#">Меню 4</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="#">Меню 5</a> </li>
  </ul>

  <button class="btn">кнопка</button>
  <div class="box_tell">
    <p>(097) 948-61-83</p>
    <p>(095) 836-90-32</p>
  </div>
</div><!-- .box_navbar_collapse -->

<div class="text-center">
  <span>|</span>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
  <span>center</span>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
div, p, ul, li, a, span, img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding:  0;
  margin:   0; }

.box_navbar_collapse{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #999;
  align-content: stretch;
  oveflow: hidden;
  width: 100%; }

a.navbar-brand {
  width:10%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f99;
  overflow: hidden; }

a.navbar-brand img {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  margin: 0 auto; }

.navbar-nav{
  width: 65%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #FF9600;
  overflow: hidden;}

.navbar-nav li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 50%; }

.navbar-nav li:not(:last-child){
  border-right: 1px solid #333;}

.navbar-nav li a{
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #184129;
  border: none;
  width: 10%;
  display: block; }

.box_tell {
  background-color: #403427;
  width: 15%;
  display: block;
}

.text-center {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #1B5D42;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Вот [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/157dr96p/3/).

Всё стили которые ненадо, можешь удалить. Я так, чисто для наглядности. Больше про flexbox можна почитать [тут](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/).

Comment: Ваш пример немного не то, что я хотел. В вашем случае пункт меню 3 должен стоять напротив метки "center" при любом разрешении . Я так понимаю что ширина для левого logo и ширина кнопки с телефонами должны быть одинаковы. Тогда меню останется  по середине. [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/157dr96p/4/)

Comment: @Raz-Dva Метка `center` в любом разрешении будет находиться ровно по центру страницы. Можете объяснить что именно надо, сейчас переделаю

Comment: вот [ПРИМЕР](https://jsfiddle.net/157dr96p/4/)
здесь центр меню всегда совпадает с центром страницы. Я хотел это сделать без фиксированой ширины элементов

Answer (score 0):

Очень удобно для Flex использовать Bootstrap, где все можно сделать через предустановленные классы.

Вот раздел документации http://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.2.1/utilities/flex/

Comment: что может быть хуже бутстрап

Comment: кто-то любит писать на чистoм коде, изобретая велосипед и наступая на старые грабли, а кто-то пользуется front-end и собирает свою идею из уже готовых "кубиков".  Я лишь предложил простой и надежный вариант. Использовать его или нагромождать кучей кода страницу - выбор у каждого свой ;-)

Comment: спору нет, сделать приложение быстрым, или увеличить размер бандла и раздуть дом-дерево ненужными распорками - выбор у каждого свой ;-)

Comment: исключительно дружеское и дружелюбное препирательство)